# He popped out to shortstop vs He popped to shortstop (What's the meaning of the sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> 1. He popped out to shortstop. 2. He popped to shortstop.

What's the meaning of the two sentences and is there any difference in their meaning?

Dictionary says 'pop' = 'hit' a pop-fly but what's the 'out' here? Does it mean the batter is 'out' now (failed to get on base)?

Comment: Bear in mind that only baseball fans are likely to understand usages like this - which mean nothing at all to the average Brit, for example. About the only thing I know about "domain-specific jargon" in the field of baseball is that they use the verb ***to fly*** in such a highly specialised way that it's effectively become a different verb to the one describing what birds and helicopters do, with different conjugation. Hence in baseball, it's [*Diaz **flied** out to center field*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Diaz+flied+out%22), not ***flew***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence means the batter in a baseball game hit a fly ball that was caught by the shortstop before it hit the ground, and was thus out.  Out means the player has to leave the playing field until the next time at bat or until the side at bat stops being at bat (which happens after three outs). A pop fly is when the batter hits the ball and it goes more up than out (a high arch trajectory).  This happens when the bat hits the ball at angle.

The second sentence is something that wouldn’t be used, and doesn’t mean anything.